# Creath an array by input in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, input, store

I would like to create an array to store the name of different departments of the company. First of all, I make users to input the total amount of departments and then create a array, allowing users to key in the name of departements.
But the compiler said the index of array is out of range.

```
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array

deptnum = InputBox("Please enter the total amount of departments.")

For k = 0 To deptnum
x = InputBox("Please enter the name of department:"
x = myarray(k)
Next
```

Comment: sorry, is to "create"

Comment: Dont't use an array. Instead, use a COllection, or better still, a scripting.dictionary.

Comment: search `redim preserve` and `ubound`. That's what you need.

Comment: @cyboashu I will do that! thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you still use the array, you can use the [redim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) array, then use array(index) to assign the name you have entered.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim departments() As String
    Dim x As String

    deptnum = InputBox("Please enter the total amount of departments.")
    If Not (IsNumeric(deptnum)) Then Exit Sub
    ReDim departments(deptnum - 1)

    For k = 0 To deptnum - 1
        x = InputBox("Please enter the name of department:")
        departments(k) = x
    Next
End Sub
```